# Runtime permission Request pauses activity

Tags: android, android-activity, video-streaming

I have an activity with a video stream. In this activity there is a snapshot button which saves a jpg with the current frame on the phone storage.

I need a `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to do that, so I implemented the runtime permission request from SDK 23.

The problem is, every time the permission is requested the activity is paused. This is fine when the dialog is showing up, it makes sense because the dialog is now in the front focus, but when you check the "never ask again" box, every time the user presses this "Snapshot" button the activity is paused and resumed again.

For a regular activity this would not be a problem but for my video streaming activity I have to stop the stream in `onPause()` and then restart it again in `onResume()` so this results on the video reloading and thus a noticeable pause.

Is there a way to prevent this? Is this even expected behavior?

Answer (score -3):

Ideally the permission should only be asked once.

Add the following code before asking for the permission.

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE); 

if(permissionCheck) {
// Permission has already been granted.
} else {
//Request for permission again.
}
```

Go through this : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-check

Comment: I have that very same code. But if you reject it the first time, then you can ask the user again. Then the user can choose not to be asked ever again. This is the use case I have trouble with.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?